# Delaying image processing using CarrierWave and DelayedJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, delayed-job

I am trying to implement a background process using DelayedJob during the process of creating a new product and uploading/resizing an image with CarrierWave (all done in the save method)

I have a page where a photographer can upload a new image along with title, desc, etc.

The new record isn't saved until everything is processed successfully so I am getting an error when I try to delay the process on line '@photo.delay.save'

```
def create
@photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
if @photo.delay.save
  flash[:notice] = "Your new photograph is being processed."
  redirect_to @photo
else
  flash[:notice] =  "Please check that all the fields were entered"
  render 'new'
end
```

end

## ERROR

```
job cannot be created for non-persisted record: #<Photo id: nil, title: "prod number 8526", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, id_num: "jh878", year_taken: "2015", is_active: false, show_bw_conversion: false, format_id: 1, rotating_keyword: "picture", slug: nil, qty_sold: 0, photographer_id: 5, daily_deal: nil, default_mat: 1, default_frame: 1, description: "<p>This is the description3895</p>", qty_download: 0, film_type: "digital", image: nil>
```

Is this strategy even possible or should I have the photographer list the title, desc, etc so that a new record is cleanly saved and then just run a delayed job for uploading/resizing the image using Carrier Wave?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

The photo row needs to be saved to the database first before you can reference it in a delayed_job.

I would make the file upload part of the photo completely separate from the photo metadata. So the file gets posted via ajax (maybe saved to s3), and then the s3 filename is posted with the rest of the metadata in the form.

Also, `@photo.delay.save` can't work, because the point of delayed_job is that the job runs in some other process at some later point in time.  You aren't going to be able to access the result of that later process in this controller action.

Comment: How would I skip the image upload process during `@photo.save` ?